# The value of the property 'MSOTlPn_ShowToolPane2' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: 2010, javascript, internet-explorer

I have a problem with SharePoint 2010 and Internet Explorer 11. The following error message appears when I try to open the webpart menu.

In Internet Explorer 8 the wepart menu works as expected:

[image]

In Internet Explorer 11 the wepart menu fails to open:

[image]

...and the following error occurs:

[image]

`The value of the property 'MSOTlPn_ShowToolPane2' is null or undefined, not a Function object`

To open the site in compatibility view or Enterprise mode is not an option.

Comment: Compability view should be an absolute option when working with SharePoint 2010 in modern IE, why is it not so for you?

Comment: Because it's an demand from the customer to run "real" IE11 and SP2010.

Comment: After trying to solve this and looking in blogs, I used Chrome to accomplish my task with success (Edit a page).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add your SharePoint page to the Internet Explorer 11 Compatibility View settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the master page "Edit mode" includes the javascript file called "ie55up.js"

Include the file "ie55up.js" in the Master Page using the `<SharePoint:ScriptLink>`

as follows:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="ie55up.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" />
```

[Reference](http://kvdlinden.blogspot.in/2010/04/open-tool-pane-javascript-error-in.html)

Comment: This solution is good, but not exactly right. When I try this the web part menu doesn't show and the edit page are directly loaded.